# Найти смещение описанного прямоугольника

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Есть квадрат и прямоугольник известных размеров. К прямоугольнику применяются произвольные трансформации в виде смещения, поворота и масштабирования.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего нужно применить к нему трансформацию смещения и масштабирования так, чтоб все четыре вершины квадрата находились внутри прямоугольника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моей фантазии хватило только на перебор всех вариантов поворота и сравнения расстояния до вершин. Может есть более правильный алгоритм?

Comment: "перебор всех вариантов поворота" - и сколько у Вас этих вариантов?

Comment: 16 - каждая сторона прямоугольника с каждой вершиной квадрата.

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю. На картинкe нет поворотов. В тексте - тоже.

Comment: Зависит от того, как выполняется трансформация. Например, если масштабирование выполняется относительно центра прямоугольника, кратчайшее смещение всегда нулевое.

Comment: @Akina не всегда. Представьте прямоугольник тех же размеров, что и на первом рисунке, но правый верхний угол квадрата лежит на его короткой стороне.  И сделайте масштаб относительно центра прямоугольника такой, чтобы его длинные стороны прошли через углы квадрата.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Да ладно... При  масштабировании относительно центра увеличиваются все размеры прямоугольника - и длина, и ширина. Рассмотрите предельный вариант - прямоугольник мы увеличили до бесконечности, он полностью "вылез" за границы отображаемой области, т.е. накрыл всю эту область, включая и квадрат...

Comment: @Akina На сколько я понимаю постановку задачи, требуется не просто прямоугольник, вмещающий в себя квадрат, а именно описанный, то есть такой, чтобы его стороны проходили через три вершины квадрата.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Я не вижу ничего, что бы говорило о таком условии. Это претензия вообще-то к автору, который вместо нормального и полного описания задачи вывалил свою полу-хотелку и успокоился...

Comment: @Akina Про "успокоился" - согласен. А  про условие - заголовок вопроса. **_Найти смещение описанного прямоугольника_**

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Показанный на рисунке прямоугольник не является описывающей фигурой согласно классическому определению (согласно ему описывающий квадрат прямоугольник также является квадратом). Так что автор явно использует термин не по назначению, либо придумал своё собственное толкование термина.

Comment: @Akina на уровне учебных заданий и с оговорками такое толкование встречается, хотя классическому определению и не соответствует. К слову, я не уверен,  что вообще существует классическое определение многоугольника, описанного вокруг другого многоугольника. Там будет столько оговорок, что определение потеряет смысл

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133689/discussion-between---and-akina).

Comment: Классическое определение описанного многоугольника требует, чтобы все вершины вписанного многоугольника лежали на его сторонах. Всё остальное - это уже частные интертрепации, которые требуют точного определения в каждом конкретном случае, чего я в вопросе не наблюдаю.

Comment: @Akina такое определение придется окружать огромным количеством дополнительных оговорок, начиная с выпуклости многоугольников.  И я так и не нашел нигде хоть какого-то внятного определения  многоугольника, описанного около многоугольника. Около окружности есть, а вот около многоугольника не нашел. Может, поделитесь ссылкой?

Comment: Вершины должны находиться ВНУТРИ прямоугольника, или на его сторонах (три вершины из четырех)?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Есть квадрат и прямоугольник известных размеров. К прямоугольнику применяются трансформации в виде смещения, поворота и масштабирования. После чего нужно применить к нему трансформацию смещения и масштабирования так, чтоб все четыре вершины квадрата находились внутри прямоугольника.

Comment: @nazarpunk это не ответ на мой вопрос. У Вас в заголовке речь идет об описанном прямоугольнике. Ближайшее приближение к описанному - три вершины квадрата на сторонах прямоугольника. В вопросе совсем другое: вершины квадрата внутри. Это две разные задачи, и решения у них разные.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов две или три вершины должны находиться на сторонах прямоугольника.

Comment: @nazarpunk И это тоже существенно разные задачи. Укладываем на стороны две смежных вершины квадрата, и масштабируем прямоугольник чем больше, тем лучше, чтобы гарантированно накрыть квадрат. Или рассчитываем  строго определенные размеры и положение прямоугольника, чтобы три вершины легли на стороны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. Поворачиваем оба объекта так, чтобы прямоугольник стал параллелен осям X Y
2. Задача превращается в определение масштаба квадрата (теперь повернутого), чтобы его размер стал равен меньшей стороне прямоугольника (тривиально).
3. и поиск смещения для расположения квадрата внутри прямоугольника (тоже тривиально).
4. И в конце, смещение надо "повернуть" обратно (обратить поворот из п.1), чтобы оно было в оригинальной системе координат.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133703/discussion-on-answer-by-kromster----).